# Regular expression to match all links that contain specifics words in anchor?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a regular expression in PHP to extract the links a text that contain the specific words (apple, home, car) in the text of anchor.

Important: the formatting of links is not known in advance.

E.g:

```
<a href="fruit.html">The Apple red</a>
<a href="Construction.html#one">The big Home</a>
<a href="automotive.html?lang=en">Car for rent</a>
```

Desired result:

```
fruit.html
Construction.html#one
automotive.html?lang=en
```

My pattern:

```
/<a.*?href="(.*)".*?>apple|car|home<\/a>/i
```

**Update:** This pattern works

```
'/<a.+href=["\'](.*)["\'].*>(.*(?:apple|car|home).*)<\/a>/iU'
```

Comment: I'm pretty horrible at RegEx but here's a starting point for you. `[^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)`. `Group 1: String`, `Group 2: Href`, `Group 3: Text`. All you really have to do is to figure out how to **multiline** match and how to **compare** against `Group 3`. [**Regex101 Link**](https://regex101.com/r/vhGd9X/1)

Comment: @Alex, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and use [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get the `<a>` elements.

Then you might use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and a regex with an alternation with the words you want to find and add word boundaries to make sure the words are not part of a larger match. To account for case insensitivity you could use the `/i` flag.

[`\b(?:apple|big|car)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/HW2rmZ/1)

```
$data = <<<DATA
<a href="fruit.html">The Apple red</a>
<a href="Construction.html#one">The big Home</a>
<a href="automotive.html?lang=en">Car for rent</a>
<a href="fruit.html">The Pineapple red</a>
<a href="Construction.html#one">The biggest Home</a>
<a href="automotive.html?lang=en">Cars for rent</a>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $element) {
    if (preg_match('#\b(?:apple|big|car)\b#i', $element->nodeValue)) {
        echo $element->getAttribute("href") . "<br>";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/p3AOG)

That would give you:

```
fruit.html
Construction.html#one
automotive.html?lang=en
```